# What creature could this be?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

I've had a friend, in a 3.5 / Pathfinder game, pull up a creature with abilities I haven't seen. It (in his description) was a shade, but it had the ability to mimic my movements and upon contact, take my physical form and turn me into a shade.  Any explanation?

Comment: Did the DM control this (*ahem*) shady creature or was the "shade" a fellow PC? When this "shade" touched your character, what happened? (Did you keep or lose control of your character? Did your character gain or lose special abilities?)

Comment: Remember it could possibly be a homebrewed creature!

Comment: Do you have any more information on it? Because from this description it could be any number of creatures. 3.5 has a LOT of books.

Comment: +1 for homebrewed creatures. Nothing is more boring than having players ID some creature and them have a script for dealing with them because they've read the Monster Manual or whatever too.  The unknown is where the excitement lies. "There are more things in heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy"

Answer (score 4):

### That's the Shadow Simulacrum Template

It was introduced in [Shadowdale: The Scouring of the Land](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowdale:_The_Scouring_of_the_Land) (pg. 156).

The template can be applied on a living creature, it must have 10 HD or more, and a minimum Charisma score of 6.

It grants a Supernatural Ability called **Possession**, which works similarly [Magic Jar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicJar.htm), but with some changes. This posession has no set duration, and no way to free the target is given, other than killing the possessed target, or [abilities that specifically deal with posessions.](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Exorcist_(3.5e_Class))

The creature is *incorporeal* when not possessing another creature, and lives on the plane of shadows.

### The Shadovar

In the Forgotten Realms campaign setting, there are [a group of shades](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Shade) called the [Shadovar](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Shadovar), which were created by a specific ritual that infuses a creature with part of the plane of shadows.

> By removing a part of your soul and replacing it with the essence of shadow, a Shade could be produced. This is an extremely complex and painful process but the result is a being with a prolonged life, and a greatly strengthened set of abilities when in the presence of shadows.

Comment: Various other supplements have provided general rules for exorcism, though, that would presumably apply to this creature’s possession as well.

Comment: Indeed. I was refering only to the ability as given though. Specific rules should be able to remove the posession.

Comment: Im unsure how to explain how his friend became a shadow, but that most likely was due to it being victim of a shadow shard, not the shadow simulacrum herself.

Comment: Interestingly, while the template *can* be applied to any creature that meets the listed criteria, a creature can only create a shadow simulacrum of *itself.* (So, for example, if this is the correct answer and the PCs got a good look at the shadow simulacrum (no easy task!), the PCs may be able to discern its creator.)